# Select a Valid Choice XXX is not one of the available choices ... but value appears in selection

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple form with a choice field:

```
class seguimentTutorialForm(forms.Form):
    pregunta_select  = forms.ChoiceField(    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pregunta = kwargs.pop('pregunta', None)
        super(seguimentTutorialForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['pregunta_select'].widget.choices=
               [('',u'---Tria---')] + 
               [ (x.strip(),x.strip(), ) for x 
                       in self.pregunta.possibles_respostes.split('|')]
```

I get this validation error on POST data:

```
Select a Valid Choice NO is not one of the available choices
```

This is the generated html form:

```
            <tr>        
                <td class="label_tag">
                                <label for="id_6_3-pregunta_select">blah blah?</label>:</td> 
                <td class="tria_tag"  class="conte_errors"    >             
                    <select name="6_3-pregunta_select" id="id_6_3-pregunta_select"> 
<option value="">---Tria---</option> 
<option value="NO" selected="selected">NO</option> 
<option value="Sí, AO">Sí, AO</option> 
<option value="Sí, AA">Sí, AA</option> 
<option value="Sí, PS">Sí, PS</option> 
<option value="Sí, UEE">Sí, UEE</option> 
</select> 

                    <br/><span class="help_text">( Tipus alumne )</span> 

                    <ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a Valid Choice NO is not one of the available choices.</li></ul> 
                </td> 
            </tr>
```

Some idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! Fixed, My mistake. To fix it change line:

```
    self.fields['pregunta_select'].widget.choices=
```

by:

```
    self.fields['pregunta_select'].choices=
```